# How can running Chrome in headless mode affect my selenium testing vs normal mode?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am currently working on a project that uses Selenium to perform automated tests on several products. I am in a disagreement with my coworker who claims that running the chrome browser in headless mode affects the quality of testing (but he does not elaborate).

So, how can running chrome in headless mode affect the quality of testing? Are there any functional differences in headless mode vs normal mode? If so, how would those differences typically affect selenium based tests at runtime?

Comment: Headless tends be faster due not having a GUI representation of the testing.

Comment: @Death one more update headless chrome doesn't support preferrences , but this has nothing to do with quality

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.chromium.org/blink

Previously headless browsers like phantomjs used to use webkit rendering engine but now chrome has inbuild headless support and uses same rendering enginee blink

so there is no effect of quality

[https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#:~:text=Headless%20Chrome%20is%20similar%20to,the%20latest%20version%20of%20Blink](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#:%7E:text=Headless%20Chrome%20is%20similar%20to,the%20latest%20version%20of%20Blink).

only thing is the headless could be little more faster

Also note w3c is on by default for non headless chrome but for headless chrome it is false and use JSONwire protocol , that doesn't affect quality of test but just for your information

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65841695/6793637

refer my above answer

## Update

As of Feb , 2021

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Headless chrome doesn't support preferrences setting . This has nothing to do with quality tho