# How to make a screenshot of a local website using phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make a screenshot of a local website using selenium.

```
import selenium.webdriver
driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/Users/username/Downloads/PhantomJS/bin/phantomjs.exe")
driver.set_window_size(4000, 3000)  # choose a resolution
driver.get('/Users/path/map.html')
# You may need to add time.sleep(seconds) here
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

`phantomjs.exe` is in the correct path, but I still get the error message :

````
WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. 
```
I habe also changed the file location of `phantomjs.exe`, but still get the same error. How could I manage that ? <br>
Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: just double click that phatomjs.exe , and then try running your code again

Comment: make sure your path is correct

Comment: why are you still using phantomjs it is not developed anymore

Comment: @PDHide the same error occurs. The path is correct.. What should I use instead to convert a local html file into image ?

Comment: Switch over to chrome and download chomedriver and than in your environment variable under PATH copy the absolute path of the chromedriver.exe. Same deal with any of them.

Comment: why not using chrome .chrome headless etc ?

Comment: Phatomjs is wprking in my system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66285381/6793637

Comment: I use python and google chrome